# Session Invalidate not Working with LTPA-based Security

Tags: java, session, authentication, websphere, websphere-7

I normally handle site logout with a JSP that executes <%= session.invalidate() %> then redirects to the home page. Now I am running on WebSphere authenticating using LTPA and a SSL Certificate. Session.invalidate() does not work. Someone suggested it is because WAS is using LTPA. LTPA creates an authentication cookie (LtpaToken2) that is not cleared by session.invalidate.

IBM does have a proprietary logout JSP*** I could use, but I don't want to use a vendor specific solution. Has anybody tackled a session logout that clears the LTPA cookie without being tied to a vendor's J2EE container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found solution:

- In the administrative console, click `Security` > `Global security`
- Under `Custom properties`, click `New`
- In the Name field, enter `com.ibm.ws.security.web.logoutOnHTTPSessionExpire`
- In the Values field, enter `true`
- Click `Apply` and `Save` to save the changes to your configuration
- Resynchronize and restart the server